# I had a web application and I would like to separate some service into another subdomain (k8s)

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I hosted my web application on AKS cluster in default namespaces.
The cluster uses Nginx Ingress, with host: example.com

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  namespace: default
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - example.com
        - www.example.com
      secretName: tls
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: service1
      port:
        number: 80
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: service1
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
      - backend:
          service:
            name: service1
            port:
              number: 8080
        path: /api
        pathType: Prefix
      - backend:
          service:
            name: service1
            port:
              number: 8080
        path: /services
        pathType: Prefix
      - backend:
          service:
            name: service1
            port:
              number: 8080
        path: /auth
        pathType: Prefix
      - backend:
          service:
            name: service1
            port:
              number: 8080
        path: /websocket
        pathType: Prefix
```

It works well with the simple setting. Nonetheless, some service needs to be separated to another namespaces. We use the same loadbalancer and would like to separate them just with another ingress in another namespaces. No changes were made to the original setting, I have deployed the required services into the new namespace togehter with the ingress as below

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-2
  namespace: ns2
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - new.example.com
        - www.new.example.com
      secretName: new-tls
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: service2
      port:
        number: 8080
  rules:
  - host: new.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: service2
            port:
              number: 8080
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
      - backend:
          service:
            name: service2
            port:
              number: 8080
        path: /api
        pathType: Prefix
      - backend:
          service:
            name: service2
            port:
              number: 8080
        path: /services
        pathType: Prefix
      - backend:
          service:
            name: service2
            port:
              number: 8080
        path: /auth
        pathType: Prefix
      - backend:
          service:
            name: service2
            port:
              number: 8080
        path: /websocket
        pathType: Prefix
```

When I tried to do some test on the config, It turns out that the request always go back to default namespaces service. Any reason?
p.s. service1 and service2 are basically the same, I just need them to handle different request from different domain/subdomain.
Thanks.

Comment: looks everything good not sure did you try just firing the subdomain and checking? there could be a chance request reaching to service and service redirecting request to main domain due to config set or so.

Comment: still if possible try sharing the yaml config files

Comment: Hi @HarshManvar, thanks for your reply, I edited the yaml for your information. Basically, the 2 service are the same, therefore, you can see that the path used are the same too. I just had no idea why the request from the subdomain still go to default namespace.

Comment: yaml looks okay could you please try adding the class of ingress controller into both ingresses once ?

Comment: @HarshManvar , I added the kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx on both yaml at first, so they should now share the same Loadbalancer. But itis still the same, all request routing to default namespace. Subdomain does not count as the domain right? I do not have any wild card on my default ingress host. wondering why.

Comment: that's weird behavior plus your yaml also looks perfect

Comment: @HarshManvar Thanks for the checking. Once you confirmed that my yaml is good enough, i focused on my service side. I just found that the ex-colleagues set up the path to call those service. I changed the env parameter and fixed it!

Comment: great to hear that, mentioned in first comment: `service redirecting request to main domain due to config set or so.`